# Infinite countable union of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A_n$ is finite $\forall n\in \mathbb N,\;$ then countable infinite union of these sets is infinite, right?

Comment: countable union of countable sets is countable!

Comment: The union could be finite.

Comment: I mean  the elements of the union will  be of infinte number right

Comment: Not nesc.  If set A_i ={1}  then the countable union will have one element.  If the sets have overlap and don't contain an infinite number of distinct items the union will be finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong.  Take for example 
$$
\forall n\in \Bbb N : A_n = \{1\}
$$
Every $A_n$ is finite (having just one element!) and the infinite union of all $A_n$ is still finite.

Comment: If they were pairwisely disjoint, this makes their union infinte right

Comment: Indeed it does.  And the proof is not difficult.

Comment: In fact, if they are pairwise unequal, the the infinite countable union is infinite.

Comment: @user480659 Since the empty set is considered finite, you may want to include non-emptiness as well :) If we set $A_n = \varnothing$, then they are finite and pairwise-disjoint, nontheless their union is empty.